# How to use Google map

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms. I am confused as to which Plugin for google map I should use to avoid problems later on.

Are these two the same? Are they providing the same set of functionalities and work well in Android and iOS.

1) Xamarin.Forms.maps 
2) Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMap

Need your guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms.Maps just uses the native map APIs on each platform and provided by Xamarin. There are some APIs which are abstration for displaying map. You can see the API referernce [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Xamarin.Forms.Maps/).

On the other hands, Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMap is 3rd party maps library for Xamarin.Forms optimized for Google maps. As I know, this is forked from Xamarin.Forms.Maps. Please refer to [Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps project.](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps)

Answer (score 0):

`Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMap` is no longer so you have no choice, you must use `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` only.

[image]